# Understanding how entity framework adds objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, this project I'm currently working on is using Entity Framework 4.0. Upgrading isn't an option, but I'm having rather significant issues with it that I just can't seem to understand.  Like, if I try to add a new object, and don't specify an Entity Key, it'll work just fine. And yet, running the same code again, it'll complain about the key missing. So, I add it in. Except for this oddity:

```
fac.EntityKey = new EntityKey()
    {
        EntitySetName = "Context.Members",
        EntityKeyValues = new List<EntityKeyMember>()
            {
                 new EntityKeyMember()
                      {
                          Key = "MemberID",
                          Value = fac.MemberID
                      }
            }
    };
```

The code above -doesn't- work. It'll raise an exception that the EntitySetName is invalid.
However, the code below -does- work.

```
fac.EntityKey = new EntityKey("Context.Members", "MemberID", fac.MemberID);
```

I even went so far as to check for equality, and they are memberwise, at least, exactly the same. Can someone explain to me exactly what's going on here?

It seems like there's a lot of magic going on behind the scenes, and I don't like magic in my code. Science is much easier to debug.

Comment: Can't you even upgrade to the highest 4 version? (EF 4.3.1). I started working with EF when it was beyond 4.0 and I don't remember ever having had to manipulate EntityKeys. Doesn't 4.0 do that under the hood?